# When unwrapping by sphere projection, how to separate the vertices at the poles and spread apart evenly, like the default mapping for a UV sphere?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

For a sphere-like object, I've unwrapped it using sphere projection. The resulting UV looks like this, with a single vertex at the pole (ignore the squiggly lines for now):

[image: result of UV mapping by sphere projection]

I would like to modify this to be more similar to blender's default mapping for a UV sphere, which separates the top vertex into multiple triangles with an even spread:

[image: Default UV mapping for a UV sphere, with evenly spread triangles at poles]

Is there a way to do this quickly and perfectly, that isn't just repeatedly ripping vertices and trying to eyeball their placement?

You can reproduce the results of the first image by viewing a UV sphere from the side and pressing U -> "Sphere projection" while in edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In edit mode, select the vertex at the top pole and use the Rip tool on it, **V** key.
2. Repeat for bottom pole.
3. Select all then **U** to open the Unwrap menu and choose the **Sphere projection** option.
4. From the Last Operator panel (bottom left) change the Pole option from Pinch to **Fan**.

see anim below.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. There's now an infinitely shall hole at the top though, can this be welded back while keeping the seams?

Comment: Yes, If for whatever reason there is a tiny hole at the pole, enable X-Ray mode in the viewport and box select all the vertices at the pole then hit M to open the Merge menu and choose the At Center option.

Comment: Just given it a go (not actually had a chance until now) and you don't even need to rip the vertex, just changing the pole to "fan" is what I was missing originally. Once again thank you for the answer